# How to draw multiple lines with xline

Tags: matlab

Is there a simple, no fuss way in Matlab of drawing multiple vertical lines using `xline()`. I have a vector of coordinates that I need to use draw vertical lines, but `xline()` does not seem to support this. Other implementations I've found online I don't understand and don't seem to apply.

```
x = [2 4 6 8];

%How to do this??
verticalLines(x)
```

Is this simple operation possible? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you know your y-axis limits, you can simply use the `line` command:

```
x = randi(100, 1, 10)
x =
   83    70    32    96     4    44    39    77    80    19
line([x;x], [-5; 5].*ones(size(x)))
```

where +/-5 corresponds to the y-axis limits.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `hold on` at the start of your file. This stops MATLAB from overwriting previous plots. I highly advise you to look at some introductory tutorials from MATLAB website, as this is basic functionality you can learn there.

Comment: I’m familiar with hold on and your approach is not feasible because I have hundreds of lines. Ideally, I was hoping to do this without a for loop

Comment: Why are you not using a for loop? It took me about 17 seconds to execute 500 xline() calls with a for loop. If you have even more lines than that can you explain a little bir further what you are trying to achieve as I can't really understand the situation

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use `arrayfun`

```
verticalLines =@(x) arrayfun(@xline, x, 'uni', false);
```